# Rack::Static how to serve an asset file (css, js etc) file containing a fingerprint value in its name so as to cache bust it

Tags: javascript, css, ruby, browser-cache, rack

In my Rack-based app I want to serve CSS and JS and so I use `Rack::Static` middleware as shown below:

**config.ru**

```
use Rack::Static, urls: ["/css" ], root: "public"

run MyApp
```

`public` folder structure:

```
public
  css
    application.min.css
```

As per `Rack::Static` implementation at https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/2.2.4/lib/rack/static.rb (link refers to code in the version of Rack I am using i.e. 2.2.4) by default `Cache-Control` header will not be set
in Response.

But if I use following configuration

```
use Rack::Static, urls: ["/css" ], root: "public",
    :header_rules => [
      # Cache CSS/JS files, matching given regex in public caches (e.g. Rack::Cache) as well as in the browser. For e.g. myfile.1.2.1.css
      #
      [ /\.(?:[1-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])\.(?:css|js)\z/, {'cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=60'} ]
    ]
```

Then I can see following header `Cache-Control: public, max-age=60` under Response Headers for e.g. in Network tab under Web Developer Tools in Firefox.

Now I want to cache bust that CSS file using fingerprint strategy as explained in following resources I found

https://css-tricks.com/strategies-for-cache-busting-css/#aa-changing-file-name

https://csswizardry.com/2019/03/cache-control-for-civilians/

So in my HTML pages I would have my stylesheet name include the fingerprint version for e.g. like following

```
<head>
  ...
  ...

  <link href="/css/application.min.<MY_ASSET_VERSION>.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

where say `<MY_ASSET_VERSION>` is set to `1.0.0`.

But I should not have any file by name `application.min.1.0.0.css` in my `public` folder. That naming is just done so as to trigger cache bust. So how can I make `Rack::Static`
to serve the file `css/application.min.css` when it encounters path `/css/application.min.1.0.0.css`?

Will I need to implement a middleware which should be put in application's middleware stack after `Rack::Static`? If yes, can anybody please help me with an example because I have not implemented any middleware.

Or if there is any other standard way for addressing the need at hand, then please suggest that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Posting below the solution which I implemented using a middleware and which is working for me.

**middlewares/custom_middleware/util.rb**

```
module CustomMiddleware
  module Util
    extend self

    EXTENSIONS_OF_ASSETS_TO_BE_FINGER_PRINTED = /css|js/
    ASSET_FINGER_PRINT_FORMAT_REGEX = /[1-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]/

    FINGER_PRINTED_ASSET_NAME_MATCHER_REGEX = /\.(?:#{ASSET_FINGER_PRINT_FORMAT_REGEX})\.(?:#{EXTENSIONS_OF_ASSETS_TO_BE_FINGER_PRINTED})\z/
    ORIGINAL_ASSET_NAME_DETERMINER_FROM_FINGER_PRINTED_NAME_REGEX = /(.+)\.(?:#{ASSET_FINGER_PRINT_FORMAT_REGEX})\.(#{EXTENSIONS_OF_ASSETS_TO_BE_FINGER_PRINTED})\z/

    def determine_original_asset_name(fingerprinted_asset_name:)
      md = fingerprinted_asset_name.match(ORIGINAL_ASSET_NAME_DETERMINER_FROM_FINGER_PRINTED_NAME_REGEX)

      return fingerprinted_asset_name if md.nil?

      arr = md.captures

      asset_file_name = arr[0]
      asset_file_extension = arr[1]

      asset_name = "#{asset_file_name}.#{asset_file_extension}"

      asset_name
    end
  end
end
```

**middlewares/custom_middleware/fingerprinted_asset_name_modifier.rb**

```
require_relative 'util'

module CustomMiddleware
  class FingeprintedAssetNameModifier
    def initialize(app)
      @app = app
    end

    def call(env)
      env_path_info_key = 'PATH_INFO'

      orig_path = env[env_path_info_key]

      modified_path = Util.determine_original_asset_name(fingerprinted_asset_name: orig_path)

      if modified_path != orig_path
        env.merge!(env_path_info_key => modified_path)
      end

      @app.call(env)
    end
  end
end
```

**config.ru**

```
require_relative "middlewares/custom_middleware/fingerprinted_asset_name_modifier"


use CustomMiddleware::FingeprintedAssetNameModifier

use Rack::Static, urls: ["/css", "/js" ], root: "public",
    :header_rules => [
      # Cache CSS/JS files in public caches (e.g. Rack::Cache) as well as in the browser. For e.g. myfile.css
      [ %w(css js), {'cache-control' => 'public, max-age=60'} ]
    ]


run MyApp
```

With above solution when following CSS file is included in my page

```
<head>
  ...
  ...

  <link href="/css/application.min.1.0.0.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

`application.min.1.0.0.css` file serves my file at `public/css/application.min.css` and in Response headers `Cache-Control: public, max-age=60` is set implying the after 60 seconds if `application.min.1.0.0.css` is re-requested it will be served from my application and not from browser's cache.

Also within 60 seconds of 1st request to the asset if changing the asset fingerprint in page like following

```
<link href="/css/application.min.1.0.5.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and reloading the page, the asset is served from my application and not from browser's cache.

Hoping that this turns out to be useful to people who may come up with a requirement like in question post.

Thanks.